# C++ Exception bypassing catch on clang/llvm

Tags: c++, clang++

I have a unit test like this:

```
TEST_F( SocketServerTest, ParseTest ) {
  try {
//    throw InvalidAddressException( "bla" );
//    auto x = dv::socket::parseEndpoint( "127.0.0.1" );
    EXPECT_THROW( auto x = dv::socket::parseEndpoint( "127.0.0.1" ), InvalidAddressException );
  } catch ( const InvalidAddressException &e ) {
    FAIL() << boost::diagnostic_information( e, true );
  } catch ( const std::exception &e ) {
    FAIL() << boost::diagnostic_information( e, true );
  } catch ( ... ) {
    FAIL() << "bla";
  }
}
```

That works with GCC and MSVC but with clang somehow the exception is caught by the default google test catch and I get

```
unknown file: Failure
C++ exception with description "Invalid address 127.0.0.1 no port number" thrown in the test body.
```

If I throw the exception directly in the test it works, if I call the code without the EXPECT_THROW it hits the default c++ exception handler and aborts the program.

It does the same thing on apple clang & clang 8 on osx, and clang 7 on fedora 29 but works with gcc on fedora 29 and msvc 2019 on win 10

The exception is in a shared library and is defined using preprocessor macros and cmake generated header file to do the visibility attributes.

Other exceptions that are defined in the same way work in other places and the same exception works when thrown from different code in the same library.

Ive tried pulling just this code out into a standalone cmake project but can't get it to fail in the same way

How can I debug why this is happening, I've been at it for days with no progress.

Answer (score 0):

After writing all that I realized I had **attribute**((pure)) on parseEndpoint removing that and it all works.